# What does it mean to linearize the trace of Gauss-Codazzi relations?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, curvature, trace, linearized-theory

[image: THe]

What does it mean to linearize the trace of the Gauss-Codazzi relations?

The equations referenced above are the following:

[image]

Reference to the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0511096

Comment: There are two steps. (1) Take the trace of the Gauss-Codazzi equations, (2) write the metric as $g=\bar{g}+h$ where $\bar{g}$ is the background metric and $h$ is a perturbation, and expand the traced GC equations to linear order in $h$. Do you know how to do either of these steps?

Comment: Thank you @Andrew but I am not sure about the second step because in the paper "_h_" is the original metric in use. What I have done till now is write the trace of equation (1.5) and use (1.4) in place of the 3 Ricci tensor. But I am not able to proceed henceforth.

Comment: @Andrew, as it turns out just using $K_{ij} = \Delta K_{ij} + \hat{K}_{ij}$ and substituting it in the trace of the Gauss Codazzi equation does the wor but I am not sure if this is correct in the sense that, it seems like more of a circular result.